# When a duplicate value exists, only get the row that has columns that are not blank

Tags: sql, ms-access, duplicates, unique, distinct

I have a Customer table inside an Access database that looks like this:

| CustomerNo | CustomerName | City | State |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | Jill Vale | LA | CA |
| 5678 | Chris Redd | DEN | CO |
| 9101 | Leon Kerr |  |  |
| 2345 | Ada Wray | PHX | AZ |
| 2345 | Ada Wray | LV | NV |
| 2345 | Ada Wray |  |  |
| 6789 | Sherri Bell | SF | CA |

"Ada Wray" shows up 3x, because 2 records have her in 2 locations, while the other record is blank.

I want to use a query in Access to pull all UNIQUE customer information, but if a duplicate customer exists, only pull the record that has the `City` and `State` filled out.

Output should look like this, where Ada Wray's record only shows up twice with both the records that have the City and State populated:

| CustomerNo | CustomerName | City | State |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | Jill Vale | LA | CA |
| 5678 | Chris Redd | DEN | CO |
| 9101 | Leon Kerr |  |  |
| 2345 | Ada Wray | PHX | AZ |
| 2345 | Ada Wray | LV | NV |
| 6789 | Sherri Bell | SF | CA |

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 1):

you can try using row number

```
select * from  (
    select row_number()over(partition by customerno order by city desc,state desc) rn, * from Customer
)tcustomer where rn=1
```

make row number based on customerno and then order it make sure the blank field sort at the last of row number, then you can subquery it and select the first 1 row number only

Comment: Does MS Access support this? (OP has replaced the original dbms tag...)

Answer (score 1):

Ms-Access does not support row_number (and many other things).
Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM Customer
         WHERE  City IS NULL AND 
        State IS NULL AND  
                CustomerName NOT IN 
                    (SELECT CustomerName FROM Customer 
                            WHERE City IS NOT NULL AND 
                                  State IS NOT NULL)
UNION
SELECT * FROM Customer
         WHERE City IS NOT NULL AND 
               State IS NOT NULL
```